# Subtraction of SUM from one column

Tags: sql, firebird

I have table look similiar to this:

```
LocalAmount Firm_id Date    StoreCard_Id
1000        5532    46,545  14124
2000        5325    46,545  13124
30000       25235   46,545  14141
1500        2525    46,545  14214
2134        25235   46,545  14241
144150      2525    46,545  41441
```

And I can SUM localAmount in one year with this code:

```
select sum(II2.LocalTAmountWithoutVAT) as "Celkem"
from IssuedInvoices2 II2
join IssuedInvoices II on II.id = II2.parent_id
join firms F on F.id = II.firm_id
left join StoreCards SC on II2.StoreCard_ID = SC.ID
left join ABI_StoreCardsWithMenu(sc.ID) SCWM on SCWM.OUT_StoreCard_ID = SC.id
where
     ib_decodedate_year(II.docdate$date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
    and F.id = '@{_firmID}'
group by 
    out_menu1Text
order by
    out_menu1Text
```

But I need to do the same for two years and substraction this two SUMS. It must to be in one SQL code.

Sorry for bad interpretation of my problem, but I don't know how I can explain it better.
Thx for all reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when ib_decodedate_year(II.docdate$date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
                then II2.LocalTAmountWithoutVAT
                else 0
           end) as ThisYear,
       sum(case when ib_decodedate_year(II.docdate$date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1
                then II2.LocalTAmountWithoutVAT
                else 0
           end) as LastYear,
       (sum(case when ib_decodedate_year(II.docdate$date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
                 then II2.LocalTAmountWithoutVAT
                 else 0
            end) -
        sum(case when ib_decodedate_year(II.docdate$date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1
                then II2.LocalTAmountWithoutVAT
                else 0
           end)
       ) as Diff       
from IssuedInvoices2 II2 join
     IssuedInvoices II
     on II.id = II2.parent_id join
     firms F
     on F.id = II.firm_id left join
     StoreCards SC on II2.StoreCard_ID = SC.ID left join
     ABI_StoreCardsWithMenu(sc.ID) SCWM
     on SCWM.OUT_StoreCard_ID = SC.id
where F.id = '@{_firmID}'
group by  out_menu1Text
order by out_menu1Text;
```